# GitLab: prevent pushing on a branch except when tag

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my configuration, a GitLab CI pipeline is triggered when a tag is pushed. I would like to be able to create and push the tags from the main branch, but I also would like to enforce using merge requests in any other case (ie. protect the main branch to forbid pushing non-tagged commits on the main branch).

Is there a way to do this? Or is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a git hook. I won't be able to write the code up today, but I'll favorite this question and come back to it.